# How to get an action for div with id in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to hide a `p` with the `id=2` and I get nothing the `p` with `id=2` don't be hidden!
whats my error

the code:

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p.2").hide();
      });
      $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p.2").show();
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <p id="2">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to show and hide a `<p>` element with the class 2 but you only have a `<p>` element with the *ID* 2. It should be like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p#2").hide();
      });
      $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p#2").show();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="2">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p#2").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p#2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="2">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

This is search a element `p` with **class** `2`

```
$("p.2").hide();
```

Should be `#` for **id**

```
$("p#2").hide();
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, please do not forget to approve or vote, otherwise make a comment to improve the answer. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)